# Laravel validation for ensuring difference in values

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-8, rest

For the below code , i don't want the `password` field to have the same value of `currentPassword` field. The desired output is to show some validation error like "password & currentPassword canot be the same" ,when one types same value for both password & currentPassword fields. To be more precise, it should work in opposite of the rule - `same` does.

```
$validator = Validator::make(
            $request->all(),
            [
                'currentPassword'     => 'required',
                'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
            ]
        );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would expect the rule to be named "NotSame", but it is not. Instead the validation rule is called `different`.

```
'password' => 'different:currentPassword'
```

Comment: Mostly passwords are hashed, so will it work for hashed values too?

Comment: It's on input and there passwords aren't hashed

Comment: Ah my bad, I did not understand the question well, lol +1